# Some questions & problems using kaleo workflow

Tags: xml, content-management-system, workflow, liferay, liferay-6

I have few questions regarding workflow:

1. In workflow definition file (`*.xml`) how can I get the previous task?
   For example, when I am on an update task, can I get the previous task such as previewer-1 or previewer-2 that had sent the request.
2. When using `<fork>` tag to fork a single transition to two tasks, say P-1 and P-2, on P-1 task if I reject the content it seems to be rejected only for this task i.e. P-1 and not for both the tasks; Now if I submit the content for the second time, it will again fork to 2 branches and I will get 3 tasks: `P-1 & P-2` and `P-2`, this will cause big trouble!
3. Another problem, when on task P-1 and P-2 the content has been changed at the same time, it will change to content of latest save, not sync, how can I make it sync (or at least, lock this content until one has been done)?

Comment: Can you elaborate the point-3, to explain it better?

Comment: thanks for edit ^^z, i'm really not good at english.

Comment: 3. Create wofkflow with fork tag. the workflow:
Creator: create content and submit->fork: to 2 task, p1 and p2 ->
       >login previewer1, and previewer2 in 2 browser
       >previewer1 assign p1, and previewer2 assign p2
       >previewer1 edit content on his task, previewer2 do it also
       >previewer1 save content, previewer2 save content after previewer1
       >The content replace with content that had saved by previewer2(and changed from previewer1 not apply)